# ¿Como probar el control de errores en un procedimiento almacenado?

Tags: mysql, sql

¿Saben cómo puedo llamar al procedimiento almacenado para que me muestre el mensaje de error "MYSQLEXCEPTION, transacción abortada? Por más que intento sólo me muestra el mensaje de error: cuenta inexistente.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE transacciones.transferir(IN monto DECIMAL(7,2), IN cuentaA INT, IN cuentaB INT)
-- Comienzo de la lógica del procedimiento
BEGIN
  -- Declaración de variable
  DECLARE saldo_actual_cuentaA DECIMAL(7,2);
  
  -- Definición del manejador de excepciones para capturar errores SQL
  DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    -- En caso de excepción, se muestra un mensaje y se realiza un rollback de la transacción
    SELECT 'SQLEXCEPTION!, transacción abortada' AS resultado;
    ROLLBACK;
  END //
  
  -- Inicio de la transacción
  START TRANSACTION;
  
  -- Verificar si las cuentas existen en la tabla "cuenta"
  IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE numero = cuentaA) AND
     EXISTS (SELECT * FROM cuenta WHERE numero = cuentaB) THEN
    
    -- Obtener el saldo de la cuentaA y actualizar el campo con el valor de la variable definidaa 
    SELECT saldo INTO saldo_actual_cuentaA
    FROM cuenta WHERE numero = cuentaA FOR UPDATE;
    
    -- Verificar si el saldo actual de la cuentaA es suficiente para realizar la transferencia
    IF saldo_actual_cuentaA >= monto THEN
      -- Realizar la transferencia: restar el monto de la cuentaA y sumarlo a la cuentaB
      UPDATE cuenta SET saldo = saldo - monto WHERE numero = cuentaA;
      UPDATE cuenta SET saldo = saldo + monto WHERE numero = cuentaB;
      SELECT 'La transferencia se realizó con éxito' AS resultado;
    ELSE
      -- Mostrar un mensaje de saldo insuficiente si el saldo actual de la cuentaA no es suficiente
      SELECT 'Saldo insuficiente para realizar la transferencia' AS resultado;
    END IF;
    
  ELSE
    -- Mostrar un mensaje de error en caso de que una o ambas cuentas no existan
    SELECT 'Error: cuenta inexistente' AS resultado;
  END IF;
  
  -- Confirmar la transacción
  COMMIT;
END //
```

Answer (score 0):

El procedimiento almacenado que has proporcionado parece estar configurado correctamente para manejar excepciones y mostrar mensajes de error específicos. Sin embargo, es posible que no estés obteniendo el mensaje "MYSQLEXCEPTION, transacción abortada" porque la excepción que estás capturando no es una excepción de tipo SQLEXCEPTION.

Puedes modificar el manejador de excepciones para capturar cualquier tipo de excepción modificando DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION por DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND, SQLEXCEPTION. De esta manera, podrás capturar diferentes tipos de excepciones, incluyendo SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND y SQLEXCEPTION.

Aquí tienes el código actualizado:

```
-- ...

-- Definición del manejador de excepciones para capturar diferentes tipos de errores SQL
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLWARNING, NOT FOUND, SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
  -- En caso de excepción, se muestra el mensaje "MYSQLEXCEPTION, transacción abortada"
  SELECT 'MYSQLEXCEPTION, transacción abortada' AS resultado;
  ROLLBACK;
END //

-- ...
```

Al agregar SQLWARNING y NOT FOUND junto con SQLEXCEPTION, deberías poder capturar una amplia gama de excepciones que podrían ocurrir durante la ejecución del procedimiento almacenado.

Recuerda que la forma en que se manejan las excepciones puede variar según la versión de MySQL y la configuración específica del servidor. Asegúrate de verificar la documentación de MySQL para obtener más información sobre el manejo de excepciones en tu versión específica.

Espero que esto te ayude a capturar y mostrar el mensaje de error deseado. Si tienes más preguntas, no dudes en hacerlas.

Comment: Hola Cristian, te falta agregar a tu respuesta una forma de probarlo. Por ejemplo: Modificar el campo `saldo` a `TINYINT(1)` y que el valor a guardar sea mayor o `UNSIGNED` y que el valor a guardar sea negativo. Saludos!

Comment: Cierto, mis disculpas Marcos

Comment: Los procedimientos almacenados no _muestran_ mensajes de error. Se ejecutan en el servidor de base de datos, donde usualmente no hay nadie a quién mostrar nada, ni los medios para mostrarlos.